# Clicking UIButton in UITableView clicks on multiple buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I select one button in my `UItableView` other buttons lower down are also clicked. I am using target action on a button in a custom tableview and changing the title of sender in the method. Why is this clicking one button selecting multiple `UIButtons`? Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using a sectioned tableview

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.section;
    return cell;
}

-(void)likeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
    [sender setTitle:@"Pressed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: If you're generating your `likeButton` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it's getting repeated because table views recycle cells.

Comment: I added this but it did not fix the issue: `    if (cell== nil) {
        cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
` @rebello95

Comment: Not what I said. Please post all code relevant to that button. Is the button initialized via code or interface file?

Comment: It is initialized via the interface file of the custom cell. @rebello95

Comment: So when one button is tapped other buttons in the section have their title changed as well?

Comment: It seems like every cell that is not loaded in has its value changed. I also have one cell for each section.

Comment: Hmm. Try adding this line before adding the target of the like button: `[cell.likeButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Nope. It actually seems like the buttons are being alternated between on and off when just one is pressed. This is a very strange bug. @rebello95

Comment: Sorry man, I have no idea then lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PostTableViewCell.h define a Delegate

```
@protocol HandleCellInteractionDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) didPressButton:(NSString*)action forCell:(UITableViewCell *)theCell;
@end
```

In TableView.h register as a Delegate for this protocol

```
<HandleCellInteractionDelegate>
```

In TableView.m file add the delegate handler

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Create cell
    ....
    cell.delegate = self;
    if (self.qObjects current object's selection state == selected)
        enable button
    else
        disable button
 }
```

Add the function for protocol
    #pragma mark HandleCellInteractionDelegate

```
-(void) didPressButton:(NSString*)action forCell:(UITableViewCell *)theCell{
    // Now here you have access to your cell again. And you can update the cell's button text as needed
    // Here save selection state in data model.. in self.qObjects <==
    cell.questionTextView.text = @"bla bla";

}
```

Comment: It says assigning retained object to weak property.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue can u mark button as strong?

Comment: Nope, now nothing happens when I click the button. Could you take a look at the entire project on gitHub?

Comment: would love to.. link?

Comment: https://github.com/SamKirkiles/qSocialNetwork The classes involved are FeedTableViewController and PostTableViewCell Thanks!

Comment: Hi.. i am able to repro the issue in a test project.. let me ask you this.. when the action is clicked, do you need to store that state change in the cell? Or just the label update is fine.. because even if you update the label once correctly, when you scroll up and down that update will be lost because the cell will be drawn again.. your answer will influence my suggestion on how to go about this

Comment: Basically I need to change change the state of the button to selected and have it stay that way when the cell goes out of view and comes back. Thanks

Comment: Looks great and I think this might be the solution but it UITableViewCell is the superclass. How can I have a parameter of PostTableViewCell in the method?

Comment: `-(void) didPressButton:(NSString*)action forCell:(UITableViewCell *)theCell;` Shouldn't it be (PostTableViewCell *)?

Comment: sure you can.. but you can also pass in the derived class pointer and then in the delegate implementation typecast it to derived class.

Comment: Thanks it works for when I want to change the textfield but setting the button to selected is the problem. I think the button is being reused between cells or something. Sorry this is such an annoying issue. Do you know how I can change the selection of the button? I committed the changes on github.

Comment: change the button's view to show its selected? [self.likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed.png"] forState: forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: Yes, it shows that the button is selected but it also shows that the other buttons in the tableview are selected too. I used `[cell.likeButton setSelected:YES]`

Comment: that is a little weird.. is it possibly only happening on ios8.. can you try it on iOS 7?

Comment: change your deployment target

Comment: Do you think creating my own type of unbutton with a uiview work?

Comment: thats weird.. can you check in the parse framework and all that too.. so i can compile the project myself and take a look?

Comment: what do you mean? isn't the parse framework included?

Comment: Do you think you could add the frameworks manually? here is the link: https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/latest If not included these must be added too: AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: will you be able to run the project with those frameworks added?

Comment: yes.. i am able to. We are on the right track and very close. This is what you have to do. in didPressButton function, update your data model to store the selected = true info. someplace where you are storing the answers (i think it would be in self.qObjects), add another BOOL param called selected and set that to true in didPressButton. And in cellForRow.. set the cell.likeButton.selected  based on what you set in self.qObjects for this header/row.. make sense?

Comment: yw! happy to help.. btw there were a couple of crashes because your loginComplete segue was set to push instead of modal

Comment: Yeah ik. There are many things that need to be fixed added or changed. Thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 0):

In your uitableviewcell subclass, make sure you are only adding a button to the cell during init. Otherwise you will add an additional button to the cell each time the tableviewcontroller calls dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Try This:
// Add a property to your custom cell to hold the indexPath

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

      PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      // Configure the cell...
      cell.indexPath = indexPath;
      return cell;
   }
```

And in your cell subclass wire up an action method, something like this:

```
  - (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", self.indexPath);
  }
```

Comment: I added the property for the button in the cells custom class. Should I have done something different?

Comment: Can you post the subclass please?

Comment: `@interface PostTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *likeButton;@
@end` @gosbra

Comment: Remove the target/ action that you included in cellForRowAtIndexPath. And add something like this to the implementation of PostTableViewCell: - (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", self.indexPath);
}

Comment: Same exact issue as before. Every other 2 cells displays the same title as the one cell that it is supposed to change to.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have Multiple Rows in a section so all button of that section get selected 
use 
 cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
instead of
  cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.section;